# Access an Array inside an Object with square brackets inside a ngFor

Tags: html, angular

Basically, I've created a HTML that similar to the example :

```
<div *ngFor="let formElements of formTemplate">
 <div *ngFor="let opt of staticEnumVals[formElements.testId]">
  <!-- do smth here -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Basically formTemplate is an Array with Objects, each Object has a property called "testId".
staticEnumVals is an Object thats build like that

```
 {
  "testId": [ {},{},{} ],
  "testId2" [ {},{},{} ],
 }
```

The keys "testId" and "testId2" are actual keys that match the Keys from formTemplate[i].testId.
Basically I want to iterate through an array out of my staticEnumVals and the array is selected dynamically based on the id from the first *ngFor

Basically im looking for an elegant way to achieve my second iteration, square brackets doesnt work.
I think my problem is clear enough, im sorry for the weird title.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding types to the staticEnumVals this worked for me.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: `
      <div *ngFor="let formElements of formTemplate">
          <div *ngFor="let opt of staticEnumVals[formElements.testId]">
              {{opt.name}}
          </div>
      </div>
  `
})
export class TestComponent {
   private formTemplate: { testId: string }[] = [
    {testId: '3'}, {testId: '2'}, {testId: '3'}
  ];

  private staticEnumVals: { [id: string]: [any] } = {
    '1': [{name: 'id1'}],
    '2': [{name: 'id2'}],
    '3': [{name: 'id3'}],
  };




}
```

Comment: Sadly adding types is not an option right now.Im doing a HTTP-Request to a extern REST-API to "get" formTemplate and staticEnumVals. Some Property-types can be difference from Request to Request (which is ofc NOT good but I cant make any BIG changes right now). Im just sure that "testId" is a String and staticEnumVals[formElements.testId] is an array

Comment: I changed the type of staticEnumVals[formElemts.testId] to any in my answer. This should be sufficient for your usecase and still works. Also typing formTemplate with an interface like {testId:string} would be possible. Like you said all those objects fullfill this interface and typescript don't care if it has any other properties

Comment: "staticEnumVals: { [id: string]: [any] }" this alone helped me, should have tested it before! But thanks you so much